# find missing sequence invoice series vbnet and oracle query

Tags: vb.net, oracle

for my question too many answer i know but there is only for numbers

i have invoice list with difference series like this

```
B012020000000001
B012020000000003
M402020000000001
M402020000000002
M402020000000004
O092020000000001
O092020000000003
E412020000000001
E412020000000003
B022020000000001
B022020000000003
```

in this list i must find

```
B012020000000002
M402020000000003
O092020000000001
B022020000000002
E412020000000002
```

and my list rows big den 100.000
i tried some codes but very slow and not worked

how can i do this
and i must add this i have two list
first one in excel file
second in oracle database

in this work i have two table in oracle database

first one is İnvoice table like as above

second table like this

[image: invice serial list]

Comment: What's your oracle version?

Comment: i dont know  version its my company database:(

Comment: Quote from the comment below: " but in table starting with B01,A40,E41 And length of invoce series are 16 characters like B012020000000001"

Comment: But looks like "202" is also hardcoded value.

Comment: provide the results of this query: `select
  max(length(regexp_substr(invoice, '^(.*\D)\d+$',1,1,null,1))) max_lem_prefix
 ,max(invoice)keep(dense_rank first order by length(regexp_substr(invoice, '^(.*\D)\d+$',1,1,null,1)) desc) example
from t`

Comment: `
MAX_LEM_PREFIX EXAMPLE
9 9999 `

Comment: ok, I've updated my answer with substr to match your new format mask.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned exact invoice format, so I'll show how to do this using dynamic prefix calculation:

```sql
select
   invoice
  ,regexp_substr(invoice,'^[A-Z]+') prefix
  ,regexp_substr(invoice,'\d+$'   ) suffix
  ,lead(invoice)over(partition by (regexp_substr(invoice,'^[A-Z]+')) order by invoice) next_invoice
  ,regexp_substr(lead(invoice)over(partition by (regexp_substr(invoice,'^[A-Z]+')) order by invoice)
                ,'\d+$'   ) as next_suffix
from t;
```

As you can see I use `regexp_substr(invoice,'^[A-Z]+')` to get [:alpha:] characters in the beginning to get prefixes and `regexp_substr(invoice,'\d+$'   )` to get suffix, ie your sequence number. Example with sample data and output:

```sql
with t(invoice) as (
   select * from table(sys.ku$_vcnt(
   'ABC2020000001',
   'ABC2020000003',
   'DEF2020000001',
   'DEF2020000002',
   'DEF2020000004',
   'GHI2020000001',
   'GHI2020000003'
   ))
)
select
   invoice
  ,regexp_substr(invoice,'^[A-Z]+') prefix
  ,regexp_substr(invoice,'\d+$'   ) suffix
  ,lead(invoice)over(partition by (regexp_substr(invoice,'^[A-Z]+')) order by invoice) next_invoice
  ,regexp_substr(lead(invoice)over(partition by (regexp_substr(invoice,'^[A-Z]+')) order by invoice)
                ,'\d+$'   ) as next_suffix
from t;
```

Output:

```
INVOICE       PREFIX SUFFIX     NEXT_INVOICE  NEXT_SUFFIX
------------- ------ ---------- ------------- ------------
ABC2020000001 ABC    2020000001 ABC2020000003 2020000003
ABC2020000003 ABC    2020000003
DEF2020000001 DEF    2020000001 DEF2020000002 2020000002
DEF2020000002 DEF    2020000002 DEF2020000004 2020000004
DEF2020000004 DEF    2020000004
GHI2020000001 GHI    2020000001 GHI2020000003 2020000003
GHI2020000003 GHI    2020000003

7 rows selected.
```

So we need just add generator to get final solution:

```sql
select 
  pre.prefix,
  calc.column_value as missing_sequence
from 
   (
   select
      invoice
     ,regexp_substr(invoice,'^[A-Z]+') prefix
     ,to_number(regexp_substr(invoice,'\d+$'   )) suffix
     ,lead(invoice)
         over(partition by (regexp_substr(invoice,'^[A-Z]+')) order by invoice)
        as next_invoice
     ,to_number(
         regexp_substr(
            lead(invoice)
               over(partition by (regexp_substr(invoice,'^[A-Z]+')) order by invoice)
           ,'\d+$'
         )) as next_suffix
   from t
   ) pre
  ,table(
      cast(
        multiset(
           select 
              pre.suffix
              +level
           from dual
           connect by 
              level < pre.next_suffix - pre.suffix
        )
       as sys.odcinumberlist
    )) calc
where 
  pre.next_suffix - pre.suffix > 1
;
```

Full example with sample data and output:

```sql
with t(invoice) as (
   select * from table(sys.ku$_vcnt(
   'ABC2020000001',
   'ABC2020000003',
   'DEF2020000001',
   'DEF2020000002',
   'DEF2020000004',
   'GHI2020000001',
   'GHI2020000003'
   ))
)
select 
  pre.prefix,
  calc.column_value as missing_sequence
from 
   (
   select
      invoice
     ,regexp_substr(invoice,'^[A-Z]+') prefix
     ,to_number(regexp_substr(invoice,'\d+$'   )) suffix
     ,lead(invoice)
         over(partition by (regexp_substr(invoice,'^[A-Z]+')) order by invoice)
        as next_invoice
     ,to_number(
         regexp_substr(
            lead(invoice)
               over(partition by (regexp_substr(invoice,'^[A-Z]+')) order by invoice)
           ,'\d+$'
         )) as next_suffix
   from t
   ) pre
  ,table(
      cast(
        multiset(
           select 
              pre.suffix
              +level
           from dual
           connect by 
              level < pre.next_suffix - pre.suffix
        )
       as sys.odcinumberlist
    )) calc
where 
  pre.next_suffix - pre.suffix > 1
;
```

Output:

```
PREFIX MISSING_SEQUENCE
------ ----------------
ABC          2020000002
DEF          2020000003
GHI          2020000002
```

Comment: i tried codes but result onemillion rows
i think that problem is serial no
i write example ABC,DEF,GHI
but in table starting with B01,A40,E41 And length of invoce series are 16 characters
like 
B012020000000001

Comment: @acar6783 Provide exact format of your invoices and full test case

Comment: That's not readable in the comments. Please fix your original question with real valurs

Answer (score 0):

ok, your update makes it even easier - all you need is just substr():

```sql
select 
  pre.prefix,
  pre.prefix||calc.column_value as missing_sequence
from 
   (
   select
      invoice
     ,substr(invoice,1,9) prefix
     ,to_number(substr(invoice,10)) suffix
     ,to_number(
         lead(substr(invoice,10))
               over(partition by (substr(invoice,1,9)) order by invoice)
         ) as next_suffix
   from t
   ) pre
  ,table(
      cast(
        multiset(
           select pre.suffix+level
           from dual
           connect by level < pre.next_suffix - pre.suffix
        )
       as sys.odcinumberlist
    )) calc
where 
  pre.next_suffix - pre.suffix > 1
;
```

Full test case with sample data:

```sql
with t(invoice) as (
   select * from table(sys.ku$_vcnt(
'B012020000000001',
'B012020000000003',
'M402020000000001',
'M402020000000002',
'M402020000000004',
'O092020000000001',
'O092020000000003',
'E412020000000001',
'E412020000000003',
'B022020000000001',
'B022020000000003'
   ))
)
select 
  pre.prefix,
  pre.prefix||calc.column_value as missing_sequence
from 
   (
   select
      invoice
     ,substr(invoice,1,9) prefix
     ,to_number(substr(invoice,10)) suffix
     ,lead(invoice)
         over(partition by substr(invoice,1,9) order by invoice)
        as next_invoice
     ,to_number(
         lead(substr(invoice,10))
               over(partition by (substr(invoice,1,9)) order by invoice)
         ) as next_suffix
   from t
   ) pre
  ,table(
      cast(
        multiset(
           select 
              pre.suffix
              +level
           from dual
           connect by 
              level < pre.next_suffix - pre.suffix
        )
       as sys.odcinumberlist
    )) calc
where 
  pre.next_suffix - pre.suffix > 1
;
```

Output:

```sql
PREFIX   MISSING_SEQUENCE
-------- --------------------
B012020  B0120202
B022020  B0220202
E412020  E4120202
M402020  M4020203
O092020  O0920202
```

Comment: @acar6783 that means, that you again provided wrong examples and you have non-digit characters after 7th character.

Comment: @acar6783 ok, I've updated my answer with substr to match your new format mask.

Comment: Thanks for all but i get same error again ,

I'm sory  for delaying my reply
I went out

Answer (score 0):

If you are on 12c, it's a job for lateral.

```
SELECT t.*, grp||val as missing_val
FROM   ( 
              SELECT invoice, 
                     grp, 
                     To_char(new_val,'fm000000000') AS val
              FROM   ( 
                              SELECT   t.*,
                                       val - Lag(val) over (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY val) p
                              FROM     (
                                              SELECT invoice,
                                                     Substr(invoice,1,7) grp,
                                                     Substr(invoice, 7)  val
                                              FROM   t 
                                        ) t 
                      ),
                     lateral 
                     ( 
                            SELECT val - LEVEL + 1 AS new_val
                            FROM   dual
                            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= p 
                      ) 
        ) t
WHERE  invoice NOT LIKE '%'||val;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Just now I executed again and it works perfectly fine. What exactly are you trying apart from what I have posted ? I said it needs 12c at least. Would you please post the result of SELECT BANNER FROM V$VERSION

Comment: Sory i dont know oracle version :(

Comment: Run this: SELECT BANNER FROM V$VERSION

Comment: ```  BANNER
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.1.0 Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

Comment: So, you have the old version of Oracle. And lateral was introduced in 12c. And hence it was not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    INV_SERI = "SELECT DISTINCT SERI FROM INVOICE_TABLE WHERE TIP='K'"
 MAK_EATM = "SELECT LPAD(INVOICE,3)SERI,SUBSTR(INVOICE,4,4)YEAR,MAX(SUBSTR(INVOICE,-9))SIRA FROM INVOICE_LIST" & _
 " WHERE INV_DATE<='31.08.2020' AND LPAD(INVOICE,3) IN((" & INV_SERI & ")) " & _
 " GROUP BY LPAD(INVOICE,3),SUBSTR(INVOICE,4,4)"

 LISTE = " SELECT SERI||YEAR||lpad(R, 9, '0') INVOICE FROM (SELECT SERI,YEAR,SIRA FROM (" & MAK_EATM & ")), " & _
 "(SelecT ROWnum r From dual Connect By Rownum <=(SELECT MAX(SIRA) FROM INVOICE_LIST))WHERE TO_NUMBER(R)<=TO_NUMBER(SIRA)  "
 EATTM = "SELECT INVOICE FROM INVOICE_LIST WHERE INV_DATE<='31.08.2020' AND LPAD(INVOICE,3) IN((" & INV_SERI & "))"

 sorgu = "SELECT A.INVOICE,B.INVOICE FROM (" & LISTE & ") A LEFT  JOIN (" & EATTM & ")B ON A.INVOICE=B.INVOICE WHERE B.INVOICE IS NULL ORDER BY A.INVOICE"
```

i used these codes and data came in a second